# Retrieve all posts within tag OR category?

Tags: categories, theme-development, tags

I've created a simple loop. And I have the following array for the query:

```
$live_tags = array(
    'tag' => 'live',
    'showposts' => 5,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
    );
```

Where it says `'tag' => 'live'`, I need a logic that asks:

```
if ('tag' == 'live' || 'category' == 'candy')
```

But I am unsure how to do that within the WP_Query array.

Anyone know how to retrieve posts from either tag, or category?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

```
$live_tags = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 5, // showposts has been deprecated for a long time
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'live',
    ),
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'category',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'candy',
    ),
  ),
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC'
);
$q = new WP_Query($live_tags);
var_dump($q->request);
```

Note that both the `{tax} (string)` and `showposts` arguments have been deprecated for quite some time. I would not recommend using them.